# Install linalg for ruby in MAC OS failed

Tags: ruby

I follow the below guideline to install the linalg for Ruby env.

http://www.quora.com/Installation-Instructions/How-do-I-install-Ruby-linalg-library-on-Mac

It works, but when I try to require the lib in 'irb', it raise the error.

Environment: Ruby:2.0.0-p0 lapack:3.5.0 (I also tried 3.4.0)

I already spend on 3 hours but didn't figure out the problem.
Here's the error, when I try to require the lib in command line.

It seems somewhere use 18 as parameter which exceed the max value as -2..15.

```
2.0.0-p0 :002 > require 'linalg'
ArgumentError: arity out of range: 18 for -2..15
from /Users/xxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
from /Users/xxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
from /Users/xxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/linalg.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/xxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
from /Users/xxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
from (irb):2
from /Users/xxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

I did fork and fixed compile for ruby 2/2.1.
You can try this fork: https://github.com/parallel588/linalg

Comment: There's no install.rb in your fork. How do we install it? I see the Rakefile and am currently trying `rake build`